# MacOS X Cataline requires verifying Microsoft Office products

Tags: microsoft-office, macos-catalina

My iMac is up to date with Catalina (version 10.15).

Now every time I open a Microsoft office product, it has to verify the program.
Then the application stops responding and I must force quit it and start over.

I have already changed the verification to 'No' in terminal, but it keeps reverting back.

How may I resolve this?